# How to generate the URL which shows the live logs in mesos for a job

Tags: docker, mesos

I am developing a UI in which I need to show the live logs (stdout and stderr) of jobs running in a mesos slave. I am finding out a way in which I will be able to generate a URL which will point to the mesos logs for the job. Is there a way to do the same? Basically, I need to know the slave id, executor id, master id etc. for generating the URL. Is there a way to find these information?

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox URL is of the form `http://
$slave_url:5050/read.json?$work_dir/work/slaves/$slave_id/frameworks/$framework_id/executors/$executor_id/runs/$container_id/stdout`, and you can even use the `browse.json` endpoint to browse around within the sandbox.

Alternatively, you can use the `mesos tail $task_id` CLI command to access these logs.

For more details, see the following mailing list thread: http://search-hadoop.com/m/RFt15skyLE/Accessing+stdout%252Fstderr+of+a+task+programmattically

Answer (score 1):

How about using reverse approach. You need to present live logs from stderr and stdout. How about storing them outside of mesos slave e.g., elastic-search? You will get nearly live updates, old logs available after, nice search options.

From version 0.27.0 Mesos supports [ContainerLogger](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/logging/). You can write your own implementation of ContainerLogger that will push logs to central logs repository (Graylog, Logstash, e.t.c) and then expose it in your UI.

Comment: Thank you, I think your answer is the best so far. It sucks that Mesos doesn't provide this automatically, though.

Comment: At least there was a try at [MesosCon hackaton](https://github.com/joyent/mesoscon-eu-2015-hackathon/blob/master/log-forwarding.md) but I'm not sure if it gets production ready. You can find more people interested in this feature on [Mesos users mailing list](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mesos-user/201409.mbox/<CAPAB6tBDsf5M8nrtCdGeC4dd6ZnQUFGOD3JsqH05L0+KH1zRLQ@mail.gmail.com>).

Answer (score 0):

Mesos offers a REST interface where you get the information you want. Visit with your browser `http://<MESOS_MASTER_IP>:5050/help` (using default port) to check the options you have to query (for example, you can get the information you need from `http://<MESOS_MASTER_IP>:5050/master/state.json)`. Check [this link](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/mesos.html) to see an example using it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur quick reponse! I am able to get all the info except container id from /master/state.json.. Is there a way to get the container id?

Comment: Please share about how did you fetch container id .